# TouchListview with fixed footer

Tags: android, layout, footer, commonsware-cwac

My question should be answered here: [Fixed footer not displaying the bottom-most list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523328/fixed-footer-not-displaying-the-bottom-most-list-item)

But it does not work for me.

I want a listview with a fixed footer at the bottom. At the moment, the listview is as large as the window, which makes the footer overlap. XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <!-- <ImageView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/baby_blue_solid" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />-->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footer_cloud"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/add_icon"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add"
    />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/cloudBG"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cl"

    />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/footer_divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
        android:layout_above="@id/cloudBG"
    />


    </RelativeLayout>

<com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.TouchListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tlv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.commonsware.cwac.tlv.demo"

    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/root"
    android_layout_above="@id/footer_cloud"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"

    tlv:normal_height="64dip"
    tlv:grabber="@+id/icon"
    tlv:remove_mode="slideLeft"

/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Although Im using a touchlistview by Commonsware, that shouldn't be a reason why it wouldn't work, I think. Can anyone spot the mistake?

Also, I can't see the divider I implemented. Both when I use the background or src attribute, no effect is visible.

Comment: This site suggest a height of 0dp for the list: http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/
For me that just makes the list invisible. It is filled bu an arrayadapter, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fall back to a simpler widget when diagnosing problems whenever possible. If you are seeing oddities with `TouchListView`, try a regular `ListView`.

Second, your layout rules for the `TouchListView` are strange. You are trying to make the widget below its own container. And, you should be using `0dp` for the height.

Try those things. If the problem is still occurring and is unique to `TouchListView`, I will need a sample project the reproduces the error to investigate further. If the problem occurs with regular `ListView`, and what I have written here has not helped, your next step is to use Hierarchy View to try to diagnose what is wrong with your layout.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed list height to 0dp, replaced touchlistview with listview. After nothing changed, I tried the hierarchyviewer. I noticed 3 children of id/root: the list, the footer and the background imageview. I suspected the background might be the problem, so I removed it, but no effect. Root now has two children. Footer has alignparentbottom and list has above:footer