# How to have a fixed footer with scrollview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout, footer

I have been trying to use

[Fixed footer not displaying the bottom-most list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523328/fixed-footer-not-displaying-the-bottom-most-list-item)

but does not work with scrollview . 
Note i am not using listview but it is a big layouts with images and buttons . 
The footer should be positioned at the botton always even while user is scrolling . 
FourSquare has this in their app where there is fixed footer even while scrolling.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/red" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/search_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/root"
        android:background="@color/layout_bg_wallet_login"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        ------More Buttons and Images
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Seems like your trying to put the footer inside the scroll view with the code you have. If you don't want the footer to move with your scroll content, you need to keep it on the same layer as the scroll view. Put together a simple example of what I believe your looking to accomplish. (didn't use strings.xml or colors.xml in this example but they should be used in for a real project)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texthere"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="test test test test test test test test test test 
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test"
        android:textSize="35sp" >
    </TextView>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#ffff00" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texthere2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="things in your footer here"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @AJak How do you do this if you want to include footer inside scroll, not outside but always at the bottom?

Answer (score 10):

This solution has only a problem: the footer float over the scroll view and if there is not enough vertical space the footer hide the bottom part of the scroll view.

In order to be sure that the whole scroll view will be always shown I had a bottom padding to the scroll view  equals to the footer height in the example (50dp):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  >
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            .......

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/footer" >
    </include>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have the same problem and you just saved my day!!! Indeed, my footer (two buttons) was hiding the last data in the scroll view, but your solution fixes this. :)))

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but shouldnt this be bottom margin instead of padding? margin will resize the actual scrollview where as the padding will just pad it and it will still overlap the footer? in case of a z-index this could prevent u from touch/click the footer.

Answer (score -2):

You have to make your `footerview` outside of `scrollview`