# Footer at the end of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not using ListView. I have to display a footer text at the end of the screen and not below all the items of the layout. How do I do it?

Comment: Used `FrameLayout` and set `Layout` as `gravity="Bottom"`

Comment: This is a very general question.This shows that you haven't researched before asking a question.You can find the answer way easily if you try to search rather than asking it straight away on SO

Comment: Refer this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277785/how-to-have-a-fixed-footer-with-scrollview-in-android

Hope it would be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/frag1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/frag2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout with weight :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use RelativeLayout and add layout_alignParentBottom="true" to your footer view.